# Dash Cytoscape data from js script

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm trying to get node position data from Dash Cytoscape. I found this solution https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-cytoscape-returning-node-positions-from-layout/23818/4
but I can't get data from the browser console in python. How can I do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far and which part are you struggling with please ?

Comment: In defense of the OP - how can you run the js script, get the desired output, and use it with dash python? I have no idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from a js script, you could use a [Clientside Callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks). As documented [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/756562bdbb5a3b7ef48197a4f9c6bfc803fb63e6/dash/dash.py#L1058), a clientside callback

> create(s) a callback that updates the output by calling a clientside (JavaScript) function instead of a Python function

To use it, you can for example write your JavaScript code into Python code like the following:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(...)

# Using a Store component and a Button to trigger the callback
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button(id="your-button"),
        dcc.Store(id="js-data")
    ]
)

app.clientside_callback(
"""
function (n_clicks) {
    // Insert your JS code here and return
    ...
    return data
}
""",
Output("js-data", "data"),
Input("your-button", "n_clicks")
)

@app.callback(
    Output("..."),  # This depends on your application
    Input("js-data", "data")
)
def work_with_js(data):
    # Do whatever you want with your data
```

As you can see, the example uses a Button to trigger the JavaScript code and returns some data in a [`dcc.Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) component. This data is used in another callback afterwards and can be manipulated.